# Node post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

I'm trying to alert a log in success box after user has enter the name and pw using node server..This is the code for the button

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var user,pass;
        $("#submit").click(function(){
          user=$("#user").val();
          pass=$("#password").val();
          $.post("/login",{user: user,password: pass}, function(data){
            if(data)
              {
                alert("login success");
              }
          });
        });
      });
</script>
```

This is the code for the post method..

```
 app.post('/login',function(req,res){
  var user_name=req.body.user;
  var password=req.body.password;
   console.log("User name = "+user_name+", password is "+password);
 res.sendStatus(200);
  res.end("yes");
});
```

Also, can i know where is a better place to learn these? like how does people kow res.sendStatus is there & how do use it ?

Comment: to answer the only question in your post ... express has [documentation](http://expressjs.com/)

Comment: I don't think you need to use `res.end()` as `sendStatus` will set the status and respond to the client. More info about the functions you use: http://expressjs.com/es/api.html

Comment: @DanielReinoso - but without `res.end("yes")` the client wont get `yes` in the response

Comment: how do i know the $.post jquery method to prompt the box? i followed the way w3school uses it but it didn't prompt ..

Comment: I would use `res.status(200).send('yes')`. From express documentation about `res.end()`: _Use to quickly end the response without any data. If you need to respond with data, instead use methods such as res.send() and res.json()._

Comment: @DanielReinoso , what can i do next after getting the request to prompt the box?

Comment: @newB I don't really know, what do you want to do next?

Comment: check the `data == 'yes'` for the value returned.. not just `if(data)`

Comment: i did data =='yes' and res.status(200).send('yes') but it didn't do the alert("login success") @DanielReinoso

Comment: try returning `res.json({ message : "yes" })` and then `if(data.message == 'yes')`. Just by using`res.send("yes")`, sends it as plain `text/html`, i think.[res.send()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) , [res.json()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json)

Comment: @Searching can''t work..